# Powershell duplicating data output

Tags: powershell

I copied the PowerShell code from [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-of-Users-from-Remote-66def6c2) site that displays the local user accounts for the computers that I want to search in my domain.

I edited it a bit to the following to show **NOT_FOUND** if that PC is turned off or just can't find it:

```
Param
(
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$false)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [Alias('cn')][String[]]$ComputerName=$Env:COMPUTERNAME,
    [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$false)]
    [Alias('un')][String[]]$AccountName,
    [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$false)]
    [Alias('cred')][System.Management.Automation.PsCredential]$Credential
)
    
$Obj = @()

Foreach($Computer in $ComputerName)
{

    If($Credential)
    {
        $AllLocalAccounts = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Namespace "root\cimv2" `
        -Filter "LocalAccount='$True'" -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    else
    {
        
        $AllLocalAccounts = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Namespace "root\cimv2" `
        -Filter "LocalAccount='$True'" -ComputerName $Computer  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable NotFound
    }

    If ($NotFound) {
        
        $Object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject

        $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value "NOT_FOUND"
        $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Disabled" -Value "TRUE"
        $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Domain" -Value $Computer
        $Obj+=$Object
        $NotFound = $null
    }
    else{
        Foreach($LocalAccount in $AllLocalAccounts)
        {
            $Object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        
            $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $LocalAccount.Name
            $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Disabled" -Value $LocalAccount.Disabled
            $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Domain" -Value $LocalAccount.Domain
            $Obj+=$Object
        }
    }
    If($AccountName)
    {
        Foreach($Account in $AccountName)
        {
            $Obj|Where-Object{$_.Name -like "$Account"}
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $Obj
    }
}
```

I enter the following:

```
.\GetLocalAccount.ps1  -Computername "Comp1", "Comp2", "Comp3", "Comp4"
```

The problem is that the output seems to be duplicating. I've tried debugging in ISE and don't see this in the $obj variable.

My Output is the following:

```
Name               Disabled Domain      
----               -------- ------      
Administrator         False Comp1
DefaultAccount         True Comp1
Guest                  True Comp1
WDAGUtilityAccount     True Comp1
Administrator         False Comp1
DefaultAccount         True Comp1
Guest                  True Comp1
WDAGUtilityAccount     True Comp1
NOT_FOUND              TRUE Comp2
Administrator         False Comp1
DefaultAccount         True Comp1
Guest                  True Comp1
WDAGUtilityAccount     True Comp1
NOT_FOUND              TRUE Comp2
NOT_FOUND              TRUE Comp3   
Administrator         False Comp1
DefaultAccount         True Comp1
Guest                  True Comp1
WDAGUtilityAccount     True Comp1
NOT_FOUND              TRUE Comp2
NOT_FOUND              TRUE Comp3   
Administrator         False Comp4
DefaultAccount         True Comp4
Guest                  True Comp4
WDAGUtilityAccount     True Comp4
```

The Output should be:

```
Name               Disabled Domain      
----               -------- ------      
Administrator         False Comp1
DefaultAccount         True Comp1
Guest                  True Comp1
WDAGUtilityAccount     True Comp1
NOT_FOUND              TRUE Comp2
NOT_FOUND              TRUE Comp3   
Administrator         False Comp4
DefaultAccount         True Comp4
Guest                  True Comp4
WDAGUtilityAccount     True Comp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't clear `$obj` for each `$Computer`, so `$Obj|Where-Object{$_.Name -like "$Account"}` will produce duplicates.

Move `$Obj = @()` inside of the loop:

```
Foreach($Computer in $ComputerName)
{
    $Obj = @()

    ...
}
```

Alternatively move the last `if`/`else` code block out of the loop:

```
$Obj = @()

Foreach($Computer in $ComputerName)
{
    ...
}

If($AccountName)
{
    Foreach($Account in $AccountName)
    {
        $Obj|Where-Object{$_.Name -like "$Account"}
    }
}
else
{
    $Obj
}
```

Comment: I actually thought about that, but was worried that it would empty the string array, but it actually does make sense....